# Loading many UIImages from disk blocks main thread

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage, uikit

I have a group of local `UIImage`s that I need to load and present in successive order when their respective cell is tapped. For example, I have 20 images of a hot dog that combine to form an animation. When the user taps the hot dog cell, the cell's `UIImageView` should animate the images.

I know how to use `UIImageView`'s `animationImages` to achieve the animation. My problem is that retrieving all of these images from disk takes ~1.5 seconds and blocks the main thread.

I could instantiate a helper class in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` that loads these images from disk on a background thread so that they'll be in memory when needed, but this seems hacky.

Are there any better ways of quickly loading many images from disk?

---

Edit: These images are illustrations and thus are .png.

Edit2: Assume the sum of each image sequence is 1 MB. The image dimensions I'm testing with are 33-60% larger than the `UIImageView`'s @3x requirements. I *am* waiting to confirm final `UIImageView` size before getting correct image sets from our designers, so the time should be cut significantly with properly sized assets, but I'm also testing on a physical iPhone X.

```
class ViewModel {

    func getImages() -> [UIImage] {

        var images: [UIImage] = []

        for i in 0..<44 {
            if let image = UIImage(named: "hotDog\(i).png") {
                images.append(image)
            }
        }

        return images

    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var viewModel: ViewModel!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        let images = viewModel.getImages()
        cell.animateImageView(withImages: images)

    }
}

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    func animateImageView(withImages images: [UIImage]) {

        imageView.image = images.last
        imageView.animationImages = images
        imageView.animationDuration = TimeInterval(images.count / 20)
        imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1
        imageView.startAnimating()

    }
}
```

Comment: "My problem is that retrieving all of these images from disk takes ~1.5 seconds and blocks the main thread" Are these images by any chance unnecessarily huge in comparison to the size of the image view?

Comment: Also I'm curious as to why loading the images takes so long. It sounds to me more like the problem is that you _are_ loading them in a background thread. I suggest using Instruments to see what's really taking the time here. Also you haven't shown your actual code which makes it impossible to help in any definite way...

Comment: Preloading the images can solve this problem (tho you don't have to go all the way back to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`; why not trigger this when the view is loaded; this feels like a view or view controller responsibility, not an app delegate). But if they're taking 1.5 seconds, they must be large and/or numerous and I'd be very concerned about the peak memory usage, too. The delay may be only be one of several problems.

Comment: @matt See Edit2......

Comment: @Rob Preloading sounds viable but I have far too many cells with unique sets of images to load them.

Comment: @chicobermuda Re preloading, I'm not necessarily convinced that's a great idea, but you were the one who proposed that. I was just suggesting that `didFinishLaunching` doesn't feel like the right place to do prefetching for a view.

Comment: Assume the `UIImageView` is 75x75 points, and each image is 300x300 pixels at 24 KB. Like I said, 33% larger than @3x requirements but I am testing on iPhone X device.

Comment: I would just point out that if you've already got images with sequentially numbered names, you can just load them all at once and assign them as animated image to the image view by calling [animatedImage(named:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624094-animatedimagenamed) _once_ instead of loading them all up into an array one by one like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you try `UIImage(contentsOfFile:)` instead of `UIImage(named:)`. In my quick test and found it to be more than an order of magnitude faster. It's somewhat understandable because it's doing a lot more (searching for the asset, cacheing the asset, etc.).

```
// slow

@IBAction func didTapNamed(_ sender: Any) {
    let start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    imageView.animationImages = (0 ..< 20).map {
        UIImage(named: filename(for: $0))!
    }
    imageView.animationDuration = 1.0
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1
    imageView.startAnimating()

    print(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start)
}

// faster

@IBAction func didTapBundle(_ sender: Any) {
    let start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    let url = Bundle.main.resourceURL!
    imageView.animationImages = (0 ..< 20).map {
        UIImage(contentsOfFile: url.appendingPathComponent(filename(for: $0)).path)!
    }
    imageView.animationDuration = 1.0
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1
    imageView.startAnimating()

    print(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start)
}
```

Note, this presumes that you had the files in the resource directory, and you may have to modify this accordingly depending upon where they are in your project. Also note that I avoided doing `Bundle.main.url(forResource:withExtension:)` within the loop, because even that had an observable impact on performance.

Comment: Excellent solution. Roughly 11.7x faster for me. Thanks, Rob.