# Swift - Animate Image sequence

Tags: swift, image, animation

I have a list of images that I want to animate in Swift. I have tried to find the best possible way to do that - but I still have some problems.

The way I animate my image-list right now is by:

```
var animatedImage = UIImageView()
var velkomstImgList = [UIImage]()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    animatedImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.scrollView.frame.width, height: 200)
    animatedImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    scrollView.addSubview(animatedImage)
    animateVelkomst()
}

func animateVelkomst() {
    for i in 0...150 {
        velkomstImgList.append(UIImage(named:"Velkomst_\(i).png")!)
        if i == 150 {
            self.animatedImage.animationImages = self.velkomstImgList
            self.animatedImage.animationDuration = 5.0
            self.animatedImage.startAnimating()
        }
    }
}
```

It works and the animation appears as expected. But the `for` loop in the beginning takes pretty long time and I dont think this is the right way to show the animation. Any suggestions on how I should animate the image sequence?

Comment: `UIImage(named:)` is slow. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49471068/1271826.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animation using array of images in sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040528/animation-using-array-of-images-in-sequence)

Comment: @Rob that depends on how the images were added to the app. If they are bundled as individual files, `init(contentsOfFile:)` might be faster, but the best thing to do is to add them to the `xcassets` folder, which will process them into a texture sheet at compile time.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez - Agreed, the `contentsOfFile` approach won’t work if they’re in `xcassets`. But, nonetheless, `UIImage(named:)` is sufficiently slow that it is likely not fast enough for quickly loading 150 (!) images just-in-time.

Answer (score 0):

loading is slow because you are attempt to load 150 images same time. you can use timer and load image when you need it.

```
let imageCount = 150
var frameIndex = 0
var timer: Timer?

func startAnimation() {
    frameIndex = 0
    let deltaTime = 5.0 / Double(imageCount)
    timer = Timer(timeInterval: deltaTime, target: self, selector: #selector(updateFrame), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func stopAnimation() {
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil
}

@objc func updateFrame(_ timer: Timer) {
    self.animatedImage.image = UIImage(named:"Velkomst_\(frameIndex).png")

    frameIndex += 1
    if frameIndex > imageCount {
        frameIndex = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: I made it work with a timer, and now the animation load the pickture individual as expected. This however, gives me another problem, the first time the app runs though the animation it is pretty laggy. Is there any way to load the image in some kind of cache?

Comment: What is dimension of images? and how mb each of them is?

Comment: you can load images data asynchronous and after than you can start animation